# Are there examples where numpy and torch give different results for broadcasting?

Tags: python, numpy, torch, broadcasting

I keep hearing that broadcasting rules are different between numpy and torch, but I cannot find any simple examples where they give different results. Are there examples where broadcasting with numpy arrays vs torch tensors give different results? Or are the differences more to do with internal stuff like copying vs pointing to elements?